How can i apply qlineargradient color only to my main QWidget
I made small app in Qt Designer and added this gradient to my main QtWidget under what all other QFrames, QTableWidget and Buttons are.
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:1, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0.427447 rgba(44, 46, 48, 1), stop:1 rgba(111, 16, 4, 1));

And when i run it, all my frames, buttons and other stuff get this gradient
enter image description here
How can i make my QFrame's, QTableWidgets and Buttons avoid this gradient and just be transparent except for the data that will be displayed there

Use proper selector types (since you're using Designer, you should use the #objectName syntax), otherwise generic properties will be propagated to all children. Note that if that top level window is QWidget subclass, you should also use setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground). If you want further help, please provide a proper [mre].
